# Undefined method 'task' using Rake 0.9.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I just updated [Rake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_%28software%29) to the latest version (`0.9.0.beta.4`) and the `rake` command ends up with the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `task' for #<Anelis::Application:0x9223b6c>
```

Here is the trace:

```
undefined method `task' for #<Anelis::Application:0x97ef80c>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/home/amokrane/Documents/prog/web/learning_rails/anelis/Rakefile:7:in `load_string'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.0.beta.4/lib/rake/environment.rb:28:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.0.beta.4/lib/rake/environment.rb:28:in `load_string'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.0.beta.4/lib/rake/environment.rb:16:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.0.beta.4/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.0.beta.4/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.0.beta.4/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.0.beta.4/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.0.beta.4/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.0.beta.4/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.0.beta.4/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.0.beta.4/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Anyone experienced the same issue? What could possibly be wrong? Note that I am running `Rails 3.0.3`, you may also be interested in the content of my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'legacy_data'
gem 'resources_controller', :git => 'git://github.com/ianwhite/resources_controller'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre' # pagination
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 0.2.6'
gem "rmagick" # sudo aptitude install libmagick9-dev
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.3"
gem "nested_form", :git => "git://github.com/madebydna/nested_form.git"
gem "meta_search"
gem "hirb"
gem "devise"
gem "rails_admin", :git => "git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git"
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I think the problem exists with rake-0.0.9 (released) as well.

Comment: you mean rake, version 0.9.0. but, yeah, it's broken.

Comment: so is this a problem with something i'm doing or a problem with this particular version of rake? Thanks, N

Comment: just came across this issue as well, trying to figure it out

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I had the same exception when running the 0.9.0.beta.4 version of Rake.
It looks like the new `Rake::DSL` is not loaded properly.

So I added following code to my Rakefile:

```
require 'rake'

# Rake Fix Code start
# NOTE: change 'Anelis' to your app's module name (see config/application.rb)
module ::Anelis
  class Application
    include Rake::DSL
  end
end

module ::RakeFileUtils
  extend Rake::FileUtilsExt
end
# Rake Fix Code end

MyApp::Application.load_tasks
```

That way I was able to run my Rake tasks again.

I know that this is not a elegant solution. But if you have to use the `--pre` version of Rake it might be all right to use this quick hack.

Comment: Thanks mordaroso for the tip!

Comment: Make sure you change the "module ::Anelis" line to whatever matches the name of your rails app.. IE "module ::Myapp" 

I forgot to do that, and this solution didn't work until I realized my mistake.

Comment: Thanks mordaroso for the tips. Change Anelis to your app name and add those magic code before the line YourAppName::Application.load_tasks otherwise the error still occurs

Comment: And make sure you put this between `require 'rake'` and `MyApp::Application.load_tasks`

Comment: Looks like this has persisted into the 0.9.0 full release. I've pulled rake back to 0.8.7 in my Gemfile.lock until this is fixed in rails and/or rake. The answer below by Andrei seems to suggest this.

Comment: Worked for me.  What i don't understand is that this happened suddenly, and i don't think i updated rake in the mean time.

Comment: Check out the code I got from the rake wiki at the bottom of the page.

Comment: instead of asking folks to remember to change "Anelis", perhaps the code snippet should just be ``Rails.application.class_eval do; include Rake::DSL; end``

Answer (score 158):

As explained in [mordaroso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4/5290331#5290331), there is a problem in Rake 0.9.0. You need to temporarily downgrade Rake in order to avoid it:

1. run: `gem uninstall rake -v 0.9` (add `sudo` unless you use `rvm`)
2. add to your Gemfile: `gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'`
3. and then run: `bundle update`

You can skip the first step, but then you have to run `rake` using `bundle exec`, for example:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Otherwise you get the following error.

```
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 0.9.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Consider using bundle exec.
```

#### Update

As Alex Chaffee noticed in a comment for [Pablo Cantero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4/6095523#6095523), that you might need to do the following to uninstall Rake if you still see the problem

```
rvm use @global && gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.0
rvm use @       && gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.0
```

Also try the solution suggested in [Duke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4/6106931#6106931).

Comment: I think this is the least "hacky" solution. You might need to run rake as `bundle exec rake` to use the working bundled version.

Comment: @Stuart K, `bundle exec rake` is needed only if rake-0.9 wasn't uninstalled. In this case one gets error message `rake aborted! You have already activated rake 0.9.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Consider using bundle exec.`

Comment: This issue also exists with Rails 3.0.7, with the Railties gem requiring Rake >= 0.8.7, which pulls in 0.9 as its available...

Comment: Even less hacky is to use: `gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'`

Comment: By "add to your Gemfile", what exactly do you mean? Where is this Gemfile? Sorry, n00b question

Answer (score 40):

**Note: This was just fixed in Rails 3.0.8**

The new version of Rake does not put its DSL commands (task, file, desc, import, etc.) in the root of the Object namespace anymore (placing them in Object meant every object has a task command, not very nice. The DSL commands are available by mixing in the `Rake::DSL module` into any module needing the commands.

Until Ruby on Rails is updated to work with Rake 0.9.x, put the following in your project Rakefile after "require rake" and before the call to `Application.load_tasks`:

```
class Rails::Application
  include Rake::DSL if defined?(Rake::DSL)
end
```

Comment: Am using Rails 3.0.7 ,with rake updated to 0.9.0 but by default in Gemfile.lock it is 0.8.7 so if we updated to 0.9.0 it works fine thanx Duke

Answer (score 16):

I've created an issue for rails_admin about this same error.

[The answer](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/428#comment_1219083):

> This is a general Rails problem: http://twitter.com/dhh/status/71966528744071169
>
> There should be a 3.0.8 release soon that fixes it. In the mean time, you can add the  following line to your Gemfile:
>
> gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'

It's a problem in Rake (0.9.0), it was [announced](http://twitter.com/dhh/status/71966528744071169) by DHH on Twitter.

> Rake 0.9, which was released yesterday, broke Rails (and others). While we wait for a fix, you'll want gem 'rake', '0.8.7' in your Gemfile.

Comment: This might not be sufficient, if your PATH still has rake 0.9.0's /bin directory on it. To really uninstall rake, you have to do `gem uninstall rake --version 0.9.0 && gem install rake --version 0.8.7` (the second install is to get the executable back).

Comment: And if rake 0.9.0 got insto your rvm global gemset, you have to do `rvm use @global &&
gem uninstall rake --version 0.9.0 &&
rvm use @ &&
gem uninstall rake --version 0.9.0 &&
gem install rake --version 0.8.7`

Answer (score 7):

This has been fixed in [Ruby on Rails 3.0.8.rc1](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/3.0.8.rc1) which should be released in a few days time.

Answer (score 3):

Rake 0.9.1 has just been released which reverses the change that caused this error but adds a deprecation warning: https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/commit/44aec3ceac085740bce0c385bccd65fc4d1d911c

Answer (score 2):

I use rvm, but uninstalling doesn't help me. So I manually remove all 0.9 files from `.rvm/gems/ruby@global` directory and everything becomes as before!

Answer (score 0):

without the need to uninstall Rake 0.9.x, add

> gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'

to your Gemfile and just type

> bundle exec rake -T

Comment: Note that 0.9.1 fixed the issue, so you can use that version instead of downgrading to 0.8.7.