# Rake 0.9.0 'undefined method 'task' '

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

Gemfile only contains rails 3.0.7 and sqlite3, all of a sudden rake will not run on any apps.The error started when running 'rake db:migrate'
Full trace output:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `task' for #<NotWorking::Application:0x00000100ccc328>
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/codywright/Code/Rails/not_working/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/codywright/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4

Comment: Good news! Rails 3.0.8.rc1 has fixed this issue, see https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/83f257fc4862642af29056cb5b7dfef6e1303754

Answer (score 8):

I did: `sudo gem uninstall rake -v 0.9` then added `gem 'rake', '0.8.7'` to my gem file.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than downgraded your Rake, you can fix your application.rb file by adding the line:

```
include Rake::DSL
```

Just add that within the class Application and you should be good!

Example application.rb:

```
module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
   include Rake::DSL
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`gem 'rake', '0.8.7'` in Gemfile works, if may also need to run `bundle update rake` if bundler complains about rake locked '0.9.0'.

Here is the issue on rake github page https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/issues/33

Answer (score 2):

I am on jruby. Here are the exact commands that got me rid of the problem.

```
jruby -S gem uninstall rake
jruby -S gem install rake -v 0.8.7
```

edit Gemfile: Add this after gem 'rails':

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

finally run:

```
jruby -S bundle update rake
```

Answer (score 0):

Run these 2 lines at the command prompt. It will remove rake 0.9.0.
substitute your username where it shows "username"

GEM_HOME='/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global' GEM_PATH='/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global'  gem uninstall rake

GEM_HOME='/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180' GEM_PATH='/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180'  gem uninstall rake

Then install the correct gems:

rvm gem install mysql2 -v 0.2.7

rvm gem install rake -v 0.8.7

Update the MySQL gem (statment here show for x86_64 intel install):

env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

When you create a new app:

rails new  -d mysql

you shouldn't need to change the gemfile or use bundle exec

I hope this makes sense. This post wont let me layout the syntax where it is readable.

Comment: you basically wrote the same thing as [@Tyler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075997/rake-0-9-0-undefined-method-task/6077849#6077849). The difference is that he did it in one line, and you added irrelevant information. What's the point? Please, [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) carefully