# You have already activated rake 0.9.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to run rails project,
I get

```
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

If I do: "bundle install"

but
I'm getting

```
You have already activated rake 0.9.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7
```

while doing

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I thank to Dobry Den, cheers dude. but little more I had to do.
here is solution (works for me).
I had added

```
gem 'rake','0.8.7'
```

on Gemfile, which was not there, but my new version of rails automatically install rake(0.9.0).

after I had delete rake0.9.0 by `gem uninstall rake`
and after doing `bundle update rake` , I can create and migrate database.

Answer (score 249):

First, check to make sure that rake is mentioned in your Gemfile. If it's not, add it, and specify the version "you already activated".

Then, you'll need to tell bundle to update the rake version it's using for your app:

```
bundle update rake
```

It'll update your `Gemfile.lock` for you.

Comment: this didn't work for me.  when i run this command it does exactly the same thing as 'bundle install' and it show that it is using the same rake version. It doesn't update it.

Comment: I had to add gem 'rake', 'version #' to my gemfile, and run 'bundle update rake' for my gemfile.lock to be updated correctly. FYI for anyone that couldn't get this solution to work for them.

Comment: I mean this may work, but is it a good idea to just add it as dependency (as opposed to leaving it as an implicit dependency) just for the sake of getting rid of an error? The real question is where is the other activated version coming from and what can you to enforce it to use the version in the `Gemfile.lock` (I don't have `rake` as a dependency in my Gemfile`)

Answer (score 45):

Where you are currently using rake commands like

```
rake db:migrate
```

Use this instead:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

this will be the case until the latest version of rails and/or rake work well together.

Comment: The bit about "the latest version of rails and/or rake" working well together only has meaning at a specific, unnamed, point in time, and under some specific assumptions about the work flow in use. I think this implication is "you're using a bleeding edge rails, and rake hasn't caught up yet." But that case can be solved by either the "bundle exec" or the "edit Gemfile" approaches as well, and these approaches also solve the problem when there are no intrinsic compatibility issues, but only a muddled workflow history.

Answer (score 8):

Rake 0.9.0 breaks rails.

See here: [Rake 0.9.0 'undefined method 'task' '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075997/rake-0-9-0-undefined-method-task)

Use `bundle exec rake` instead of `rake` to run rake at the correct version.

Answer (score 7):

Specify the version that you want in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.0'
```

then

```
bundle update rake
```

you need to use bundle exec to run your rake task

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Seems not to "un-activate" the later version.  Removing Rake entirely and re-installing works, though.

Answer (score 6):

Oh look, it's the future.  For me, it was complaining I had rake 10.x installed when it wanted 0.9.5.  Not quite sure, not familiar enough with Ruby to really dig into what happened to the recent version numbers, but what I did was:

```
gem uninstall rake
gem install rake -v 0.9.5
```

to force the system to install the version of rake that the app wanted (for me it was Octopress).

Comment: The future called, and it wants to borrow your Hammer pants.

Comment: Hi, it's the future again.  I hear Hammer pants are finally making a comeback.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem (with another gem that was not rake) and I was able to fix it by

```
gem uninstall <complaining gem>
gem install <complaining gem>

bundle install
bundle update
```

Note that the keyword 'sudo' was not used (ie. sudo bundle install) as that may place your gem into directories where your rails app might not be searching in.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your Gemfile

```
# Rake 0.9.0 break Rails.
gem "rake", "!= 0.9.0"
```

And then uninstall *rake-0.9.0*

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you're not asking, you need to open your `Gemfile` file and change the line...

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

...to...

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.0'
```

Comment: What if I want to use 0.8.7 instead of 0.9?

Comment: the rake gem isn't specified in your Gemfile by default since it's a Rails dependency. if you updated the rake gem to 0.9.0, you still have the 0.8.7 gem on your system (check with `gem list`). i'm pretty sure that if `gem 'rake', '0.8.7'` is still specified in your `Gemfile.lock`, it'll still use the 0.8.7 gem without a problem. if not, then try running `bundle` after adding `gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'` to your Gemfile (not .lock) and see if it says anything.

Comment: gem 'rake' is not defined. It takes default one if I have multiple Gem Rake (0.8.7 and 0.9.0) . Can we make default to old one?