# Rails can't see my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

**Given:**

Two controllers under `/app/controllers` named:

- customers_controller.rb (CustomersController)
- home_controller.rb (HomeController)

**Problem:**

When I run rails command (i.e. `rails c`) this is what I get:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > CustomersController
 => CustomersController 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > HomeController
NameError: uninitialized constant HomeController
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):2
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So whats the deal? Why isn't `HomeController` being recognized by my application?

**Edit:**

My home_controller.rb file:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def sign_up
  end

  def faq
  end

  def terms
  end

  def privacy
  end

  def feedback
  end

end
```

Theres not much in it.

Comment: please post the code in `home_controller.rb`.

Comment: @agentfll, code is posted. Probably not much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works for me with Rails 3.0.7 ... which version of Rails are you using?

There was a problem with old versions of Rake in the newer Rails versions, and I noticed that you're using a really old version of Rake..

Try to put this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake' , '>= 0.9.1'
```

then do a "bundle update"

and try to do "rails c" again..

does it work for you afterwards?

See also:

[Confused with rake error in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205377/confused-with-rake-error-in-rails-3)

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I think I was using this version for a particular reason that I can remember off the top of my head.