# Rake - task worked before - but now there is an error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Today I had updated my ruby and rails versions using rvm on Linux/Ubuntu.
Unfortunately, now an older applications doesn't work any more, although I haven't touched it.

```
    rake importpostings
    rake aborted!
    undefined method `map' for :needs:Symbol
```

The rake file looks like:

```
    task :importpostings, :needs => :environment do |task|
    Mail.defaults do
    ...
```

Comment: Which version of ruby and rails you are using previosuly and now.

Comment: ruby 1.9.2-p290, Gemfile says rails '3.0.9'. When I first tried to run the task there was error message that the installed rake version was higher than the requested one (not exactly sure how it was called and which versions were mentioned).

Comment: I think your rake version has got updated, try bundle install again and run the rake task.

Comment: Is there a way to find out, which rake version I need?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205377/confused-with-rake-error-in-rails-3

Comment: refer to above link you will be able to find what is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove needs and write the task like this :-

```
  task:importpostings  =>  :enviornment
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but it doesn't work. Seems that I can't access the model.

rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Object::Account

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by replacing the first line with:

```
    task importpostings: :environment do
```