# rubymine error: You have already activated rake 10.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.6. Using bundle exec may solve this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, rubymine

When I run rspec from my rubymine editor,I get this error:

```
You have already activated rake 10.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.6. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

I also tried this:

```
gem uninstall rake -v 10.0.3
```

But I get the following message:

```
INFO:  gem "rake" is not installed
```

bundle update rake fixes the issue for the command line.

But I still get the "already activated rake error" when i run rspec through command line.
I am not sure how to resolve this. I want to run 0.9.6
Do i have to update the gem file. I cannot update it and push it to remote repo because this is a shared repo everybody will be using.

Comment: Please follow this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080040/you-have-already-activated-rake-0-9-0-but-your-gemfile-requires-rake-0-8-7

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a gemset for your project try this in RubyMine:

Go to `Settings` and select `Ruby SDK and Gems` from the `Project Settings` section in the left-hand pane.
In the right-hand pane find rake in the list of gems and you'll probably see both 10.0.3 & 0.9.6 listed. Check the `Ignore global gempath` check-box and you should now see just the rake 0.9.6 version listed.
Hit OK and that should do it.

Comment: +1, i'll never have to fire up a console and type `bundle exec rake db:migrate` again. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could try `bundle update` to fix dependency issues. I had the same problem and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at version of rake your Gemfile specifies that rails should use.  It could be that your bundle update command is upgrading to a version higher than what other dependent gems expect to be available.

I would once more uninstall the gem as you've already done, and then write the following line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.6'
```

Then run a bundle install instead of bundle update.

Comment: I actually like to use `bundle exec` only as a last resort.  If all your gem versions match up correctly, then you shouldn't need it at all.  It's bundler's job to keep track of this, and it generally does a pretty good job, especially when mixed with rvm to keep different project versions separate.

Comment: @LukeMorris ..it didnt work. also, i no longer can run gem uninstall rake -v 10.0.3. Like i mentioned above it gives an error "
When I run rspec from my rubymine editor,I get this error:

You have already activated rake 10.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.6. Using bundle exec may solve this.
I also tried this:

gem uninstall rake -v 10.0.3
But I get the following message:

INFO:  gem "rake" is not installed"