# Rake db:migrate stopped working after bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Hope this is a simple question for some of you..

I've updated my gems bundle and somehow I can't migrate my db anymore..

This is the full trace:

```
Supreme:supportactie Supreme$ rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
undefined method `task' for #<Supportactie::Application:0x1037ffa40>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/Supreme/Websites/iceworld/supportactie/Rakefile:7
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Hope someone can help me out, cause I do not have any tables left to work with!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4).