# Rails - delayed job is failing after updating rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, rake, delayed-job

I've updated a couple of gems and what not, namely upgraded rails to version 3.0.7

The project has quite a few delayed_jobs in it, however now when I come to start the jobs in the terminal with the command:

```
rake jobs:work
```

I get an error message saying:

```
undefined method `task' for #<MyAppName::Application:0x10350ab78>
```

The rake file current has the follwing in it, in realation to delayed jobs I think:

```
MyAppName::Application.load_tasks
```

I was wondering if anyone new how to fix this problem and get delayed jobs running again.

Also as far as I can tell there is no problem with adding the jobs to the db, the problem is purly with starting the tasks on my local machen via the terminal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you upgrade rake? Apparently Rake 0.9 broke Rails 3.0.7:

> Rake 0.9, which was released
>   yesterday, broke Rails (and others).
>   While we wait for a fix, you'll want
>   gem 'rake', '0.8.7' in your Gemfile. - David Heinemeier Hansson

Comment: Cheers, I tried that but then I get the error message: 

'You have already activated rake 0.9.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Consider using bundle exec.'

When running rake jobs:work

Comment: @Smickie Try deleting your Gemfile.lock and then run `bundle install`. After that, be sure to restart your web server and take a look into your Gemfile.lock to ensure the right version of rake is being used.

Comment: @Smickie, you need to either uninstall 0.9.0, or use `bundle exec rake ...`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4

Answer (score 2):

This fix worked for me

[Undefined method 'task' using Rake 0.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating to the latest delayed_job plugin? run `bundle install`? what happens if you run `rails script/delayed_job start`?