# Rails - rake db:create error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Im trying to run rake db:create for a mysql database but getting the error

```
$ rake db:create
rake aborted!
undefined method `task' for #<Sharebox::Application:0x0000010085a010>
```

Ive run --trace and get the info

```
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/lucasdobbins/rails_projects/sharebox/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

This is my database.yml file

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: sharebox_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

Ive reinstalled ruby, rails and mysql but still getting the same error any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

You should precise your version of rake in your GemFile.

Rake 0.9 just got out but break Rails.

here's the tweet of [dhh](https://twitter.com/#!/dhh):

`Rake 0.9,released yesterday, broke Rails (and others). While we wait for a fix, you'll want gem 'rake', '0.8.7' in your Gemfile.`

Try that?

EDIT: Also, see [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4) if you REALLY need Rake 0.9 rather than Rake 0.8.7. Maybe that kind of fix would work for you.