# Rails : rake db:create mysql error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to setup a mysql database, but I am getting this error message:

```
rake db:create
(in /Users/yookd/Desktop/rails/blog)
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please Include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Blog::Application#task called at /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
db/test.sqlite3 already exists
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Mysql2

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any assistance with this?
(following directions on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

**EDIT:::**

How can I use mysql as my database as opposed to sqlite?  In the gemfile, it explicitly states: `gem 'sqlite'`... do I need to replace that line with something like `gem mysql`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. See: [Rails - rake db:create error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087919/rails-rake-dbcreate-error)

BUT note that Rake 0.9.1 has been released which supposedly fixes things. So first try upgrading rake with:

```
gem update rake
```

And update your bundle:

```
bundle update rake
```

Answer (score 0):

For your edit, yes, to use mysql you have to first have mysql installed and configured on your system. Then in your gemfile, remove 'gem sqlite' and replace it with:

```
gem 'mysql'
```

Then, in your config/database.yml, set it up something similar to:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: name_of_database
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  password: mysql_password
```

Do the same for test and production.