# Why can't i get rake db:migrate to work for ruby.railstutorial.org

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I decided to go through the tutorial. After I create a new app and add new `user:string email:string` and then perform `rake db:migrate` in the app directory, I get this output:

```
rake aborted! 
undefined method `task' for #<DemoApp::Application:0x00000100e49e08>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/zigloo99/rails_projects/demo_app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

I am using RVM too ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.7 as in the tutorial.
Any thoughts?

Comment: [demo_app]$ gem query

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.7)
actionpack (3.0.7)
activemodel (3.0.7)
activerecord (3.0.7)
activeresource (3.0.7)
activesupport (3.0.7)
arel (2.0.10)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.13)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.2)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.7)
railties (3.0.7)
rake (0.9.0)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.27)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined method 'task' using rake 0.9.0.beta.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is to require rake 0.8.7 in your Gemfile before starting a new rails project.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rake', '0.8.7', :require => 'rake'
```

then run `bundle install`

Answer (score 10):

This is happening because the latest version of Rake (0.9.0) is broken on Rails 3.0 applications and we are currently awaiting a solid fix.

Right now, a way around this error is to add this line above the `load_tasks` line in your application's `Rakefile`:

```
<AppName>::Application.send :include, ::Rake::DSL if defined?(::Rake::DSL)
```