# rake db:migrate error, 'task' is undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Have tried to run the rake db:migrate, returned an error.

Then ran it again with --trace, here is the error:

```
Paul-Denlingers-MacBook-Pro:things_i_bought pdenlinger$ rake db:migrate --trace
```

rake aborted!
undefined method `task' for #<ThingsIBought::Application:0x00000101679880>
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in`initialize_tasks'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in`method_missing'
/Users/pdenlinger/rails_projects/things_i_bought/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in`load'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in`raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in`standard_exception_handling'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in`block in run'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in`run'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake:19:in`load'
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake:19:in `'

It says that 'task' is an undefined method; what does this mean? And what can I do to fix it?

Running Rails 3.0.7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't i get rake db:migrate to work for ruby.railstutorial.org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091617/why-cant-i-get-rake-dbmigrate-to-work-for-ruby-railstutorial-org)

Comment: Thank you. My time on SO has been sporadic, and I'm not familiar with all the rules, but will try to understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4). You can either revert to rake 0.8.7 in your Gemfile or patch your Rakefile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.
->[Gist : broken rakefile](https://gist.github.com/984320)

Answer (score -1):

Rake 0.9.0 broke a few things.

In the meantime, try:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```