# Undefined method 'task' using rake 0.9.0 AND 0.8.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dbmigrate

while attempting to run rake, I run into the following error:

> heroku rake db:migrate
>   rake aborted!

...and the trace:

```
> undefined method `task' for #
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
> /app/Rakefile:7
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `load_rakefile'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `run'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake:31
> /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19:in `load'
> /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19
```

Gemfile:

> source 'http://rubygems.org'
>
> gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
>   gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'
>   gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

I realize that other people have reported this error and asked the same question - the posted solutions have no effect on my issue, though. I've attempted every solution listed here: [Undefined method 'task' using Rake 0.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3.0.8.rc1 has fixed this problem with rake 0.9.0, see this commit: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/83f257fc4862642af29056cb5b7dfef6e1303754

Answer (score 1):

If you keep using 0.9.0, copy the following into you're Rakefile :

```
module ::AppName
  class Application
    include Rake::DSL
  end
end

module ::RakeFileUtils
  extend Rake::FileUtilsExt
end
```

Just before

```
AppName::Application.load_tasks
```

Cheers,