# Rake db:migrate issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, rakefile

When running rake db:create or rake db:migrate locally my app successfully builds the tables as expected. When running on heroku however (eg. heroku rake db:migrate --trace --app ) it is giving me the following error all of a sudden:

```
C:\>heroku rake db:migrate --trace --app foo rake aborted!
undefined method `task' for #<Foo::Application:0x7f8e77aa1420>
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/app/Rakefile:7
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake:31
/usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19
```

Looking at the Rakefile this is all that's present:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

Foo::Application.load_tasks
```

The load_tasks line is line 7. I'm really not sure what changed but something sure has. Has anyone had experience with this error?

Comment: Can you post the `load_tasks` code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4)

There's an issue with Rake 0.9.0. Use 0.8.7 in your Gemfile for now.