# rake db:create & rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR and have been trying to complete getting started link

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I'm getting couple of problems:

1. I can't run `rake db:create`
2. I can't run `rake server`

Workstation is Ubuntu 12.04, Rails 3.2.8, Ruby 1.9.3p194.

```
mukeshk@ubuntu:~/NetBeansProjects/rails_work/blog/config$ rake db:create
(in /home/mukeshk/NetBeansProjects/rails_work/blog)
rake aborted!
undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000002080410>

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

mukeshk@ubuntu:~/NetBeansProjects/rails_work/blog/config$ rails server
/home/mukeshk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails32/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000002a02f60> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/mukeshk/NetBeansProjects/rails_work/blog/config/application.rb:54:in `<class:Application>'
    from /home/mukeshk/NetBeansProjects/rails_work/blog/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:Blog>'
    from /home/mukeshk/NetBeansProjects/rails_work/blog/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mukeshk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails32/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/mukeshk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails32/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/mukeshk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails32/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/mukeshk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails32/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
mukeshk@ubuntu:~/NetBeansProjects/rails_work/blog/config$
```

Comment: Does your application.rb include active record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your config/application.rb:

```
require "active_record/railtie"
```

Comment: Sounds like a broken configuration of Rails. Try using this tutorial, which is where I learnt Rails, and is exceedingly helpful and detailed. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:up_and_running. Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087919/rails-rake-dbcreate-error?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122966/ruby-on-rails-error-rake-dbcreate?rq=1

Comment: problem with >rails server resolved. I followed the guideline on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:up_and_running

Comment: problem with >rails server resolved. I followed the guideline on ruby.railstuturial.org only thing I changed was specifying specific version of gem in GemFile. I will update on > rake db:create issue shortly. thanks Dane Balia