# Impossible to use rake in my rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rake

Every time I try to use rake in my rails project it throw me the message below. I tried to re-install ruby, rails, rake, re-create the project, launch my *rake db:migrate* with *sudo* but nothing seems to work...
I created the object via the scaffold command:

```
rails generate scaffold User nom:string email:string
```

After this command execute succesfully, i launch

```
rake db:migrate
```

And it return this message:

```
rake aborted!
GONE
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `initialize_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/home/bassochette/Dev/rails/tuto/demo_app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

ps: I'm new to rails and in the learning phase.

Comment: seems issue with rake version you have:

Follow [the similar issue here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5290331/985051

Comment: Post the output of `rake db:migrate --trace` here.

Comment: too long for the comment but i put it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/bCQUKb6g